# How to get the difference between 2 int arrays as a percentage

Tags: c#, arrays, math

Mathematically we can solve it like Given Amount / Total Amount * 100 to get the percentage difference. But what I need is to compare 2 Integer Arrays (in C# Win App) and get the percentage of the difference.
Like :

```
1 -----> -2
2 ----->  3
3 ----->  7
4 ----->  456
5 ----->  13
```

These two columns are 2 Integer Arrays and I should get the difference between them.
How can I get this? A mathematical answer or an algorithm, whatever can be used to solve the problem.

Comment: do the math you want manually in your question, so we can understand what exactly you need.

Comment: i'm not sure if i can explain on math way ,but i need to compare to integer arrays and get the Percentage of Equality or Similarity something like that ,i need to find out in percentage how similar are 2 integer arrays .I hope i was clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who replied to the question!
I thought about a solution these days but I'm not sure about the result. I have doubts about my work because I'm debugging it but each time with another 2 Arrays which contain more than 48.000 elements.
My solution so far was like :

```
for(int i=0;i<arr1.length;i++)
{
  if(arr1[i] == arr2[i])
  count++;
}
double percentage = (float)count / (float)arr1.length * 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var i1 = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToArray();
var i2 = Enumerable.Range(20, 10).ToArray();
var result = i1.Select((n, i) => n * 100 / i2[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by difference? you can get the array of differences by:

```
int[] array = new int[arr1.Length];
for (i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
  array[i] = array1[i] - array2[i];
}
```

Comment: I mean the Percentage of difference between these 2 arrays ,like the Equality Percentage or Confidence Percentage .

Answer (score 0):

How about using `LINQ`:

```
        Int32[] array1 = new Int32[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        Int32[] array2 = new Int32[] { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

        Int32[] array3 = array1.Zip(array2, (a1, a2) => (a1 + a2) / 2).ToArray(); // Put whatever formula you want in there.
```

EDIT: `Daniel` and `CD` are correct. Code has been corrected. Thanks guys.

Comment: Now here you must make sure arrays are of same `Length`.

Comment: @decyclone - unless my math is rusty, that's average not difference.

Comment: @Joel - unless my reading skills are rusty, I can read a comment next to it.

Comment: Won't this do a cross-product/Cartesian join of the two arrays? You need to link the two arrays by index number.

Comment: @decyclone: You can use the Array.Zip method instead: `array1.Zip(array2, (a1, a2) => (a1 + a2) / 2)`

Comment: @decyclone: your reading skills must be rusty. he asked for difference not average.

Comment: @decyclone yuup im sure that these Arrays are the Equal Length each time .